# What is the problem with NHibernate 2.1.0? I always get an error!

Tags: nhibernate, proxyfactory

I've read in this post that all the ProxyFactory dependency was removed by using an interface in this [post](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2008/11/09/nh2-1-0-bytecode-providers.aspx).
So you need to specify which implementation to use in the hibernate.cfg.xml file.
I've this configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MYDB;Integrated Security=true</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect</property>
    <property name='proxyfactory.factory_class'>NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I've added a refernce to the `NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.dll`. When I run the test using MBunit, I get the error that my deployment folder should contain either `NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.dll` or `NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.dll`. I guess this is right configuration and it should work. But it is not working. I've spent much time behind this.

P.S: When I donwloaded NHibernate, the NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle project was not built. I added the project to the solution and built it. Then I referenced the assembly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same situation not too long ago.

When you say you added a reference, was it to the actual project or test project? It should be within both. Also, ensure "Copy Local" is set to true in the properties(F4) of the reference.

Another approach I took to check that if dll is within the directory that the application is running from was by calling the following prior to any of the Configuration.

```
Console.WriteLine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
```

In my situation, I learned that when using ReSharper to execute tests, it was running in a location different than I had expected and was not containing the dll. Doing a Clean Solution and rebuilding seemed to correct the issue.

Hope this gives you a couple of things to check.